# Making Phone Verification Textfield UI in flutter

Tags: flutter, uitextfield

I'm making a UI, which has a verification for the phone number. It has four codes to be input which you will get via notification from our backend. Since I'm responsible to make the UI for this, it is really not working out for me.

This is the UI which I want to achieve :

[image: Phone Verification TextField]

I have tried my level best to achieve this but I'm failing every time to achieve one.

**CODE**

```
Container(
   height: 64.0,
   width: 56.0,
   child: Card(
       color: Color.fromRGBO(173, 179, 191, 0.7),
       child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
            child: TextEditorForPhoneVerify(this.codeOne)
       )
   )
)
```

I have my own widget for the inputs :

```
class TextEditorForPhoneVerify extends StatelessWidget {
   final TextEditingController code;

   TextEditorForPhoneVerify(this.code);

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return TextField(
       textAlign: TextAlign.center,
       keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
       controller: this.code,
       maxLength: 1,
       cursorColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
       decoration: InputDecoration(
         hintText: "*",
         counterText: '',
         hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20.0)
       )
    );
  }
}
```

Now every time I use the **textAlign: TextAlgn.center**, it crashes and crashes my other textfields also. I have made a note not to use the same widget for all, they all have different widgets. When I hot restart it, it works. But this **textAlign** is something buggy.

I really want to achieve this, with the above code I'm gettin this :

**RESULT**

[image: Resultant]

And the error I get when I try to put the cursor to center is  :

```
flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
flutter: Please see the documentation for computeDistanceToActualBaseline for the required calling
flutter: conventions of this method.
flutter: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart': Failed assertion: line 1642 pos 12: '!_debugDoingBaseline'
flutter:
flutter: Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
flutter: more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
flutter: In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
flutter:   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
flutter:
flutter: When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
flutter: #2      RenderBox.getDistanceToBaseline (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1642:12)
flutter: #3      _RenderDecoration._layout.layoutLineBox (package:flutter/src/material/input_decorator.dart:820:35)
flutter: #4      _RenderDecoration._layout (package:flutter/src/material/input_decorator.dart:857:18)
flutter: #5      _RenderDecoration.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/input_decorator.dart:987:44)
flutter: #6      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #7      _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #8      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #9      _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #10     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #11     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #12     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #13     RenderPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:199:11)
flutter: #14     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #15     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #16     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #17     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #18     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #19     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #20     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #21     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #22     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1206:11)
flutter: #23     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #24     RenderPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:199:11)
flutter: #25     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #26     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #27     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #28     RenderConstrainedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:259:13)
flutter: #29     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #30     RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:738:15)
flutter: #31     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #32     RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:738:15)
flutter: #33     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #34     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:142:11)
flutter: #35     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:350:7)
flutter: #36     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:212:7)
flutter: #37     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:356:14)
flutter: #38     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #39     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #40     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #41     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #42     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1206:11)
flutter: #43     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #44     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #45     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #46     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #47     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #48     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #49     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #50     RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:510:15)
flutter: #51     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #52     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #53     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #54     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #55     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #56     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #57     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #58     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #59     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #60     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #61     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #62     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #63     RenderOffstage.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3032:13)
flutter: #64     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #65     RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:510:15)
flutter: #66     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #67     __RenderTheatre&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #68     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #69     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #70     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #71     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #72     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #73     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #74     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #75     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #76     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #77     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #78     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #79     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #80     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #81     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #82     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #83     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #84     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #85     RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:510:15)
flutter: #86     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #87     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #88     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #89     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #90     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #91     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #92     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #93     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #94     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #95     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #96     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)

Reloaded 0 of 567 libraries in 2,311ms.
flutter: #97     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #98     RenderOffstage.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3032:13)
flutter: #99     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #100    RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:510:15)
flutter: #101    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #102    __RenderTheatre&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #103    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #104    _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #105    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #106    _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #107    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #108    _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #109    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #110    _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #111    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #112    _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
flutter: #113    RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
flutter: #114    RenderView.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/view.dart:151:13)
flutter: #115    RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1507:7)
flutter: #116    PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:766:18)
flutter: #117    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:329:19)
flutter: #118    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:701:13)
flutter: #119    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:268:5)
flutter: #120    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:988:15)
flutter: #121    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:928:9)
flutter: #122    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:749:7)
flutter: #124    _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate/runtime/libtimer_impl.dart:382:19)
flutter: #125    _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libtimer_impl.dart:416:5)
flutter: #126    _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:171:12)
flutter: (elided 3 frames from class _AssertionError and package dart:async)
flutter:
flutter: The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired:
flutter:   _RenderDecoration#10671 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
flutter:   creator: _Decorator ← InputDecorator ← AnimatedBuilder ← Listener ← RawGestureDetector ←
flutter:   GestureDetector ← TextSelectionGestureDetector ← IgnorePointer ← Semantics ← TextField ←
flutter:   TextEditorForPhoneVerify ← Padding ← ⋯
flutter:   parentData: <none> (can use size)
flutter:   constraints: BoxConstraints(w=28.0, h=56.0)
flutter:   size: Size(28.0, 56.0)
flutter: This RenderObject had the following descendants (showing up to depth 5):
flutter:   RenderRepaintBoundary#9838d relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
flutter:     RenderPointerListener#95bb3 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
flutter:       RenderSemanticsAnnotations#1d581 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
flutter:         RenderIgnorePointer#7b37c relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
flutter:           RenderLeaderLayer#d035d relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
flutter:   RenderAnimatedOpacity#5b708 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT
flutter:     RenderParagraph#62bf0 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT
flutter:   RenderConstrainedBox#fb712 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
flutter:   RenderCustomPaint#7c081 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
flutter: ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: Another exception was thrown: Please see the documentation for computeDistanceToActualBaseline for the required calling conventions of this method.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: Please see the documentation for computeDistanceToActualBaseline for the required calling conventions of this method.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: Please see the documentation for computeDistanceToActualBaseline for the required calling conventions of this method.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: Please see the documentation for computeDistanceToActualBaseline for the required calling conventions of this method.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: Please see the documentation for computeDistanceToActualBaseline for the required calling conventions of this method.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: Please see the documentation for computeDistanceToActualBaseline for the required calling conventions of this method.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: Please see the documentation for computeDistanceToActualBaseline for the required calling conventions of this method.
```

Also, I'm more interested in getting this also : **As soon as the number is put the cursor should go to the next one automatically without even to press any key on keybord. As you have seen in most of the verification code layouts.**

Please help, cos I have tried my level to achieve one but couldn't get the desird result. Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use PinCodeTextField https://pub.dev/packages/pin_code_fields

You can use different shape and animation also it handle the problem which is occurs when you remove the text in middle.

Comment: Using a lot of packages can pose difficulties in maintenance for the long run.

I suggest resorting to packages whenever something really requires you to e.g Firebase functionalities, intl funcs.

Answer (score 44):

I have made my own UI,  if you like it, use it, or you can customise to your own needs

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Otp extends StatefulWidget {
  final String email;
  final String newEmail;
  final bool isGuestCheckOut;

  const Otp({
    Key key,
    @required this.email,
    this.newEmail = "",
    this.isGuestCheckOut,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _OtpState createState() => new _OtpState();
}

class _OtpState extends State<Otp> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  // Constants
  final int time = 30;
  AnimationController _controller;

  // Variables
  Size _screenSize;
  int _currentDigit;
  int _firstDigit;
  int _secondDigit;
  int _thirdDigit;
  int _fourthDigit;

  Timer timer;
  int totalTimeInSeconds;
  bool _hideResendButton;

  String userName = "";
  bool didReadNotifications = false;
  int unReadNotificationsCount = 0;

  // Returns "Appbar"
  get _getAppbar {
    return new AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      elevation: 0.0,
      leading: new InkWell(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
        child: new Icon(
          Icons.arrow_back,
          color: Colors.black54,
        ),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      ),
      centerTitle: true,
    );
  }

  // Return "Verification Code" label
  get _getVerificationCodeLabel {
    return new Text(
      "Verification Code",
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: new TextStyle(
          fontSize: 28.0, color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
    );
  }

  // Return "Email" label
  get _getEmailLabel {
    return new Text(
      "Please enter the OTP sent\non your registered Email ID.",
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: new TextStyle(
          fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
    );
  }

  // Return "OTP" input field
  get _getInputField {
    return new Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: <Widget>[
        _otpTextField(_firstDigit),
        _otpTextField(_secondDigit),
        _otpTextField(_thirdDigit),
        _otpTextField(_fourthDigit),
      ],
    );
  }

  // Returns "OTP" input part
  get _getInputPart {
    return new Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        _getVerificationCodeLabel,
        _getEmailLabel,
        _getInputField,
        _hideResendButton ? _getTimerText : _getResendButton,
        _getOtpKeyboard
      ],
    );
  }

  // Returns "Timer" label
  get _getTimerText {
    return Container(
      height: 32,
      child: new Offstage(
        offstage: !_hideResendButton,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Icon(Icons.access_time),
            new SizedBox(
              width: 5.0,
            ),
            OtpTimer(_controller, 15.0, Colors.black)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // Returns "Resend" button
  get _getResendButton {
    return new InkWell(
      child: new Container(
        height: 32,
        width: 120,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.black,
            shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32)),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: new Text(
          "Resend OTP",
          style:
              new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
      onTap: () {
        // Resend you OTP via API or anything
      },
    );
  }

  // Returns "Otp" keyboard
  get _getOtpKeyboard {
    return new Container(
        height: _screenSize.width - 80,
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Expanded(
              child: new Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  _otpKeyboardInputButton(
                      label: "1",
                      onPressed: () {
                        _setCurrentDigit(1);
                      }),
                  _otpKeyboardInputButton(
                      label: "2",
                      onPressed: () {
                        _setCurrentDigit(2);
                      }),
                  _otpKeyboardInputButton(
                      label: "3",
                      onPressed: () {
                        _setCurrentDigit(3);
                      }),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            new Expanded(
              child: new Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  _otpKeyboardInputButton(
                      label: "4",
                      onPressed: () {
                        _setCurrentDigit(4);
                      }),
                  _otpKeyboardInputButton(
                      label: "5",
                      onPressed: () {
                        _setCurrentDigit(5);
                      }),
                  _otpKeyboardInputButton(
                      label: "6",
                      onPressed: () {
                        _setCurrentDigit(6);
                      }),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            new Expanded(
              child: new Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  _otpKeyboardInputButton(
                      label: "7",
                      onPressed: () {
                        _setCurrentDigit(7);
                      }),
                  _otpKeyboardInputButton(
                      label: "8",
                      onPressed: () {
                        _setCurrentDigit(8);
                      }),
                  _otpKeyboardInputButton(
                      label: "9",
                      onPressed: () {
                        _setCurrentDigit(9);
                      }),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            new Expanded(
              child: new Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new SizedBox(
                    width: 80.0,
                  ),
                  _otpKeyboardInputButton(
                      label: "0",
                      onPressed: () {
                        _setCurrentDigit(0);
                      }),
                  _otpKeyboardActionButton(
                      label: new Icon(
                        Icons.backspace,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          if (_fourthDigit != null) {
                            _fourthDigit = null;
                          } else if (_thirdDigit != null) {
                            _thirdDigit = null;
                          } else if (_secondDigit != null) {
                            _secondDigit = null;
                          } else if (_firstDigit != null) {
                            _firstDigit = null;
                          }
                        });
                      }),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }

  // Overridden methods
  @override
  void initState() {
    totalTimeInSeconds = time;
    super.initState();
    _controller =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: time))
          ..addStatusListener((status) {
            if (status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
              setState(() {
                _hideResendButton = !_hideResendButton;
              });
            }
          });
    _controller.reverse(
        from: _controller.value == 0.0 ? 1.0 : _controller.value);
    _startCountdown();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: _getAppbar,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: new Container(
        width: _screenSize.width,
//        padding: new EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16.0),
        child: _getInputPart,
      ),
    );
  }

  // Returns "Otp custom text field"
  Widget _otpTextField(int digit) {
    return new Container(
      width: 35.0,
      height: 45.0,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: new Text(
        digit != null ? digit.toString() : "",
        style: new TextStyle(
          fontSize: 30.0,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
//            color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.4),
          border: Border(
              bottom: BorderSide(
        width: 2.0,
        color: Colors.black,
      ))),
    );
  }

  // Returns "Otp keyboard input Button"
  Widget _otpKeyboardInputButton({String label, VoidCallback onPressed}) {
    return new Material(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: new InkWell(
        onTap: onPressed,
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
        child: new Container(
          height: 80.0,
          width: 80.0,
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
          ),
          child: new Center(
            child: new Text(
              label,
              style: new TextStyle(
                fontSize: 30.0,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // Returns "Otp keyboard action Button"
  _otpKeyboardActionButton({Widget label, VoidCallback onPressed}) {
    return new InkWell(
      onTap: onPressed,
      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
      child: new Container(
        height: 80.0,
        width: 80.0,
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
        ),
        child: new Center(
          child: label,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  // Current digit
  void _setCurrentDigit(int i) {
    setState(() {
      _currentDigit = i;
      if (_firstDigit == null) {
        _firstDigit = _currentDigit;
      } else if (_secondDigit == null) {
        _secondDigit = _currentDigit;
      } else if (_thirdDigit == null) {
        _thirdDigit = _currentDigit;
      } else if (_fourthDigit == null) {
        _fourthDigit = _currentDigit;

        var otp = _firstDigit.toString() +
            _secondDigit.toString() +
            _thirdDigit.toString() +
            _fourthDigit.toString();

        // Verify your otp by here. API call
      }
    });
  }

  Future<Null> _startCountdown() async {
    setState(() {
      _hideResendButton = true;
      totalTimeInSeconds = time;
    });
    _controller.reverse(
        from: _controller.value == 0.0 ? 1.0 : _controller.value);
  }

  void clearOtp() {
    _fourthDigit = null;
    _thirdDigit = null;
    _secondDigit = null;
    _firstDigit = null;
    setState(() {});
  }
}

class OtpTimer extends StatelessWidget {
  final AnimationController controller;
  double fontSize;
  Color timeColor = Colors.black;

  OtpTimer(this.controller, this.fontSize, this.timeColor);

  String get timerString {
    Duration duration = controller.duration * controller.value;
    if (duration.inHours > 0) {
      return '${duration.inHours}:${duration.inMinutes % 60}:${(duration.inSeconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
    }
    return '${duration.inMinutes % 60}:${(duration.inSeconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
  }

  Duration get duration {
    Duration duration = controller.duration;
    return duration;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: controller,
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
          return new Text(
            timerString,
            style: new TextStyle(
                fontSize: fontSize,
                color: timeColor,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I can make the above design easily. The main concern for me is to achieve what I have put in my question. Thanks, but it is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Nope, the whole UI is different Lakhwinder. I'm not looking for that. Thanks

Comment: It's not about UI, it's about functionality you required, UI, you can change as per your requirement

Comment: I can, but I have tried and getting this error. I cannot follow the code blindly. Why I have put up a question because I couldn't get my UI come like the one which I have to get

Comment: That's your call,  to use it or not, at least you can get an idea, how you can achieve what's desired.

Answer (score 8):

```
Scaffold(
  body: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
    child:  Wrap(
      alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
      spacing: 4,
      direction: Axis.horizontal,
      runSpacing: 10,
      children: [
        _otpTextField(context, true),
        _otpTextField(context, false),
        _otpTextField(context, false),
        _otpTextField(context, false),
        _otpTextField(context, false),
        _otpTextField(context, false),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);

Widget _otpTextField(BuildContext context, bool autoFocus) {
 return  Container(
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.shortestSide * 0.13,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
    color: Colors.white,
    shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
  ),
  child: AspectRatio(
    aspectRatio: 1,
    child: TextField(
      autofocus: autoFocus,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: InputBorder.none,
      ),
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      style: TextStyle(),
      maxLines: 1,
      onChanged: (value) {
        if(value.isNotEmpty) {
          FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
        }
      },
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

Comment: Simple solution without 3rd party plugins.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`pin_input_text_field`](https://github.com/TinoGuo/pin_input_text_field).

This lib is specially designed for such text fields. It has a `decoration` property for customizing boxes.

Answer (score 5):

**To automatically shift focus to next field, a simple onChanged on TextFormField works**

```
onChanged: (str) {
  if (str.length == 1) {
     FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_nextFocusField);
  }  
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me till I added ```textInputAction: TextInputAction.go,```

Answer (score 4):

```
class EnterOTP extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
        child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              OTPDigitTextFieldBox(first: true, last: false),
              OTPDigitTextFieldBox(first: false, last: false),
              OTPDigitTextFieldBox(first: false, last: false),
              OTPDigitTextFieldBox(first: false, last: true),
            ],
          )
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
    
    class OTPDigitTextFieldBox extends StatelessWidget {
      final bool first;
      final bool last;
      const OTPDigitTextFieldBox(
          {Key key, @required this.first, @required this.last})
          : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          height: 85,
          child: AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: 1.0,
            child: TextField(
              autofocus: true,
              onChanged: (value) {
                if (value.length == 1 && last == false) {
                  FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
                }
                if (value.length == 0 && first == false) {
                  FocusScope.of(context).previousFocus();
                }
              },
              showCursor: false,
              readOnly: false,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: MyStyles.inputTextStyle,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              maxLength: 1,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                // contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                counter: Offstage(),
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(width: 2, color: primaryColor),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(width: 2, color: primaryColor),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                hintText: "*",
                hintStyle: MyStyles.hintTextStyle,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please add a description of what this code does. Only code is not as meaningful as a description of the written code.

Comment: This is not a working peice of code. Still it provides a general idea for a custom made text box. Thanks

Comment: @SwissCodeMen I added the description/summary.

Comment: because you have this MyStyles class .. but you do not put this class  here

Answer (score 3):

I know it is too late for an answer, but I tested different packages and different answers, like this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/pin_code_fields) doesn't have `readOnly` attribute, and also some answer doesn't have autofocus when we insert or delete text from `TextField`, but for me, the below code worked properly.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'const/mSize.dart';

class TestFile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestFileState createState() => _TestFileState();
}

class _TestFileState extends State<TestFile> {
  FocusNode _focusDigit1 = FocusNode();
  FocusNode _focusDigit2 = FocusNode();
  FocusNode _focusDigit3 = FocusNode();
  FocusNode _focusDigit4 = FocusNode();
  FocusNode _focusDigit5 = FocusNode();
  FocusNode _focusDigit6 = FocusNode();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
    _focusDigit1.dispose();
    _focusDigit2.dispose();
    _focusDigit3.dispose();
    _focusDigit4.dispose();
    _focusDigit5.dispose();
    _focusDigit6.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: mediaQueryData(context).size.width * 0.15,
        ),
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              CodeInput(
                focusNode0: _focusDigit5,
                focusNode1: _focusDigit6,
                focusNode2: null,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: mediaQueryData(context).size.width * 0.063,
              ),
              CodeInput(
                focusNode0: _focusDigit4,
                focusNode1: _focusDigit5,
                focusNode2: _focusDigit6,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: mediaQueryData(context).size.width * 0.063,
              ),
              CodeInput(
                focusNode0: _focusDigit3,
                focusNode1: _focusDigit4,
                focusNode2: _focusDigit5,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: mediaQueryData(context).size.width * 0.063,
              ),
              CodeInput(
                focusNode0: _focusDigit2,
                focusNode1: _focusDigit3,
                focusNode2: _focusDigit4,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: mediaQueryData(context).size.width * 0.063,
              ),
              CodeInput(
                focusNode0: _focusDigit1,
                focusNode1: _focusDigit2,
                focusNode2: _focusDigit3,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: mediaQueryData(context).size.width * 0.063,
              ),
              CodeInput(
                focusNode0: null,
                focusNode1: _focusDigit1,
                focusNode2: _focusDigit2,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CodeInput extends StatelessWidget {
  final FocusNode focusNode0;
  final FocusNode focusNode1;
  final FocusNode focusNode2;

  const CodeInput({
    Key key,
    this.focusNode0,
    this.focusNode1,
    this.focusNode2,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          width: mediaQueryData(context).size.width * 0.063,
          child: TextField(
            focusNode: focusNode1,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            maxLength: 1,
            onChanged: (str) {
              if (str.length == 1) {
                FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focusNode2);
              } else if (str.length == 0) {
                FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focusNode0);
              }
            },
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: "*",
              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
              counterText: "",
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One more package, without using keyboard
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pin_code_widget

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this my widget :

```
class ActivationFormField extends StatelessWidget {
  final int count;
  final TextEditingController controller;

  ActivationFormField({super.key, this.count = 6, required this.controller});

  final List<TextEditingController> controllers = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Wrap(
      alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
      spacing: 4,
      direction: Axis.horizontal,
      children: getFields(context),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> getFields(BuildContext context) {
    var list = <Widget>[];
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      controllers.add(TextEditingController());
      if (i == 0) {
        list.add(_otpTextField(context, false, controllers[i]));
      } else {
        list.add(_otpTextField(context, false, controllers[i]));
      }
    }

    return list;
  }

  Widget _otpTextField(BuildContext context, bool autoFocus, TextEditingController controller) {
    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.shortestSide * 0.07,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
        color: Colors.white,
        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
      ),
      child: AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: 1,
        child: TextField(
          controller: controller,
          autofocus: autoFocus,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            counterText: '',
            border: InputBorder.none,
          ),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          style: TextStyle(),
          maxLength: 1,
          onChanged: (value) {
            this.controller.clear();
            if (value.isNotEmpty) {
              FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
            }
            for (var ctrl in controllers) {
              this.controller.text += ctrl.text;
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```